# Flash URLLoader won't work on standalone SWF vs in-browser

Tags: flash, urlloader

I've got a flash game that uses xml for server responses/requests.

I use the URLRequest and URLLoader classes to send the requests to the server.

When I play the game in a browser (so I've got an index.html file around the SWF) it works but when I play the game as a standalone SWF in flash player on Windows it won't send the request to the server.

I'm not sure what's wrong. I don't see any error messages.

I believe it is using http.

Comment: Are you listening for errors on your URlLoader?

Comment: Yeah I am listening for IO error. Nothing is displayed.

Comment: Listen for security errors and network errors as well.  And global errors too is a good idea.   See my answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27573334/1457439