# How to server flash policy file with socket-io 1.3.5 (node server)?

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, socket.io, cross-domain-policy

I'm trying to serve inline flash policy file on port 3000, but with no luck.

I can not catch any callback from flash policy call (`<policy-file-request/>\0`). And I don't know how to serve send policy file back to flash through the socket.

Somethig like this: [Setting up a socket policy file server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html) from Adobe

This is code from server:

```
var server   = require('http').createServer();
var io       = require('socket.io')(server);

var port = 3000;

var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \n"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">\n<cross-domain-policy>\n';
    xml += '<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>\n';
    xml += '<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>\n';
    xml += '</cross-domain-policy>\n';

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('<policy-file-request/>\0', function (data, callback) {
        console.log('socket policy-file-request 0');
        callback(xml);
    });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    info('Server listening at ' + port);
});
```

And from client:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://example.com:3000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the socket.io connections and communications incorrectly. You have to emit to the sockets instead of using a callback method, as such (a modification of your code):

Server:

```
var server   = require('http').createServer();
var io       = require('socket.io')(server);

var port = 3000;

var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \n"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">\n<cross-domain-policy>\n';
    xml += '<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>\n';
    xml += '<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>\n';
    xml += '</cross-domain-policy>\n';

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('<policy-file-request/>\0', function (data) {
        console.log('socket policy-file-request 0');
        socket.emit('<policy-file-request/>\0', xml);
    });

    socket.on('<policy-file-request/>', function (data) {
        console.log('socket policy-file-request');
        socket.emit('<policy-file-request/>', xml);
    });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    info('Server listening at ' + port);
});
```

Client:

```
//
//Existing code (socket setup)
//

socket.on('<policy-file-request/>\0', function(data){
    Security.loadPolicyFile(data);
});
socket.on('<policy-file-request/>', function(data){
    Security.loadPolicyFile(data);
});
```

Comment: I don't think that this solution will work because of crossdomain restrictions. I'm trying to implement [adobe socket policy](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html).

Comment: @MarosPixel Oh, thanks. Which part wouldn't work then? I noticed that the socket.io part was different from what I've worked with, so I thought that might be what was causing the problem (since the callbacks don't have a connection back to the client). I don't do much with Adobe, so I didn't know that it would conflict with crossdomain restrictions. I'm guessing I set up the xml parsing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying the [npm crossdomain package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crossdomain) which I recommended as a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581656/2256820) ( take look on the comments ) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27572684/2256820) ?

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think that this package is for **http** crossdomain, and i need to implement **socket** croosdomain policy.